# Theorem on non-decreasing probability of success of an algorithm

Tags: ds.algorithms, pr.probability

Question: *What's a standard name/framework for the following, or some variant?*

Stated briefly for a probabilistic algorithm: define $p_n$ as the conditional probability of success of a fork of the algorithm after it consumed $n$ bits of randomness, knowing the other fork succeeded.

Claim: *$p_n$ is non-decreasing*.

---

Stated more in detail for a fixed deterministic sequential algorithm which input is a bitstring, that it consumes bit by bit, at most one bit at each execution step. Each run of the algorithm has the same fixed limit $t$ on the number of steps (yielding a time limit for constant step frequency), and the algorithm is aborted if it did not succeed within this limit. The outcome of any run is *success* or *abort*. Assume the algorithm aborts if it's input is shorter than what the algorithm requests.

If the algorithm succeeds for bitstring $b$, then it succeeds for $b\mathbin\|0$ and for $b\mathbin\|1$ (and won't read the extra $0$ or $1$ bit). If the algorithm aborts for bitstring $b$ with length $\lvert b\rvert\ge s$, then it aborts for $b\mathbin\|0$ and for $b\mathbin\|1$ (and won't read the extra $0$ or $1$ bit).

Assume there exists a bitstring such that the algorithm succeeds.

For an integer $n$, define $p_n$ as the probability the algorithm succeeds in the second part of this experiment:

- we repeatedly run the algorithm, with as many uniformly random independent input bits as it requests, until we find one input bitstring $b$ such that the algorithm succeeds;
- we once more run the algorithm, with input the first $n$ bits of $b$, then as many uniformly random independent input bits as the algorithm requests.

In this experiment, the algorithm never aborts because it's input is shorter than what the algorithm requests. When $n$ is larger than $\lvert b\rvert$, the last run succeeds after all the bits of $b$ have been input, since the previous run did, and the algorithm is deterministic. It follows: $n\ge t\implies p_n=1$.

Claim: *$p_n$ is non-decreasing*. That follows from this [simpler proposition](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4177838/35016), applied to the set of $t$-bit bitstrings that make the algorithm succeed.

---

I find this theorem useful in some proofs of cryptographic security, usually made with a more complex argument. See the [motivating context](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/91604/555).